# using a javascript variable in asp-route (parameter)?

Tags: c#, .net-core, razor-pages

I'm extremely new to C# and .Net Core and Razor Pages.
I'm trying to create a super simple application where you can submit your first name and last name to a form and it will redirect you to a template which accepts the parameters firstname and surname and will print them out.

So what I'm doing is that I'm currently trying to store the value of the input (only trying with the first name right now) within script tags and then adding the variable within the asp-route-firstname when you submit the form. But it doesn't seem to work. Is this even the right way to try to approach this or am I somehow supposed to do this in the @{} field at the top?

In this case it just prints out {foo} as a string and the hardcoded surname Browder.

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";

}

    <div class="text-center">
        <h1 class="display-4">Welcome @Model.FirstName</h1>
        <p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>

        <form method="post"  asp-page="/nametemplate" asp-route-firstname="{foo}" asp-route-surname="Browder">
            <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
            <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>

<script>

    let foo = document.querySelector("#fname").value;
    
</script>
```

Thank you a million times in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very basic example to get you started but I highly recommend reading the docs.

Essentially you want to look at model binding. You don't need to use JS as per your example.

[Razor Pages Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Index.cshtml

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
</div>

<form method="post">
    <input asp-for="Firstname" />
    <input asp-for="Lastname" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Index.cshtml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Policy;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace RazorPageTest.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }

        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {

        }

        public IActionResult OnPost(string firstname, string lastname)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("Display", new { firstname, lastname });
        }

        
    }
}
```

Display.cshtml.cs (new page)

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace RazorPageTest.Pages
{
    public class DisplayModel : PageModel
    {
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        public void OnGet(string firstname, string lastname)
        {
            Firstname = firstname;
            Lastname = lastname;
        }
    }
}
```

Display.cshtml

```
@page
@model RazorPageTest.Pages.DisplayModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Display";
}

<h1>@Model.Firstname @Model.Lastname</h1>
```